# Is it possible to slow down the Blue Midnight Wish cryptographic hash function?

Tags: hash

In the Blue Midnight Wish (BMW) cryptographic hash function, is there a variable I can use to increase memory/CPU resource consumption to slow down the password hashing process? Call me crazy, but I really like BMW and I'd like to use it to hash passwords. It's obscure, so a bit better, but I am also paranoid, so I need to increase hashing time.

Comment: When it comes to cryptography, "`obscure`" != "`better`". In fact, for most values, they are opposites.

Comment: I like obscure hashes. Don't blame me... Plus, I never let a hash be without a common hash, and I never let a hash without a obscure hashes (usually a few)

Answer (score 2):

You don't increase hash time (I surmise it is for hashing passwords) by tuning the hash function from within -- especially one which has been optimized to be very fast. You get slow hash time by integrating the hash function in a larger structure which runs many iterations. In any case you would not want a slowdown by a factor of 2 or 3, rather 200000.

See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) for a primer on hashing passwords. See [this site](https://password-hashing.net/) for an ongoing open competition to design better password hashing functions.

Comment: Okay, but I don't like FGPAs. I really really don't. CPUs have (compared to a FGPA) alot of memory avalible. FGPAs don't. Is there a way to Increase memory?

Comment: @user1757922 You can connect a ram chip to a FPGA. Just like how you attach a ram chip to a CPU. CPUs only have 1-8 meg of on-board ram. Just because you don't like FPGAs does not mean that a cracker doesen't. Sorry.